# Correct spelling of Polish surname Mahowski?

Tags: surnames, poland

I am looking for the correct spelling of Polish surname Mihowski or   Mahowski? I hope to find cousins in Poland.

Comment: Hi – you may find the comments and answers on this question useful: [How to find correct spelling of Polish last name?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3789/how-to-find-correct-spelling-of-polish-last-name) Also note that it would be more useful to research specific individuals rather than just a surname. For example: John Smith and Tom Smith may share the same surname but be completely unrelated, and the same is true with Polish names.

Comment: Extremely likely it was Machowski. A standalone 'h' is very rare in Polish language, but the 'ch' combination is common and is pronunced as the 'h' is most other languages (such as English or German for example).