# Spelling Polish name pronounced Ko lo jay?

Tags: surnames, poland

For sure it starts with K. Pronounced Ko lo jay. There is a d on last syllable is similar to dij.

Maybe Kolodij?

Comment: Connie, welcome. This is an extremely difficult question to answer with any certainty, but you may find this question useful: [How to find correct spelling of Polish last name?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3789/)

Answer (score 9):

If polish spelling rules are applied to "Ko lo jay" it'd look like Kolodżej.

However, **Kołodziej** is more likely to be your answer as it is a real polish family name but it is NOT pronuced "Ko lo". But instead "Ko **w**o" with a [soft **ł**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81), similar to the "W" in "Washington".